# What is the empirical formula of Haemoglobin?

Tags: biochemistry

Everywhere I look on the internet tells me a different formula. Are there genuinely different formulas for Haemoglobin, or are some of my internet sources incorrect?
(I know there are different formulas for oxyhaemoglobin, deoxyhaemoglobin, carboxyhaemoglobin, etc but the formulas I am seeing are very varied and do not account for this... I don't think)

Comment: A reliable way to get the formula would be to search for [human hemoglobin in the Protein Data Bank](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/results/results.do?qrid=9E09BD9C&tabtoshow=Current), pick the type you want, and then open the file in a protein visualization program or extract the aminoacid sequence + sidechains/intercalated molecules and calculate the formula from that.

Comment: I've gotten to this (http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/jmol.do?structureId=5EE4&opt=3&bionumber=1) page and can see the ball and stick model for Haemoglobin subunit α, how do I find the empirical formula from here?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work with proteins, so I don't know how to process that data. I don't know if you can get the formula by viewing the molecule in your browser. I think you may be able to get the empirical formula by opening the .pdb file in the appropriate software. Also, I'm not sure that's the structure you're looking for; something like [this](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=2DN2) is more likely what you want. You can also download the FASTA sequence and open it as a .txt to retrieve the aminoacid sequence for each heme subunit and maybe do something with that.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try to interpret the PDB file.

Comment: Aha! Go to the "Experimental Data & Validation" section in the protein page, then look at "View Full Validation Report". In the PDF file, go to section 2, "Entry composition", and you can find the molecular formulae for each subunit and the ligands.

Comment: Argh, I just realized that the reported composition doesn't take into account any hydrogen atoms. You'll need to insert those with a program. Not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Oh. Well, you've given me a lot to work on, and I'm very thankful for that. Perhaps I can try and cross reference the data with other data about Haemoglobin subunit α which includes the hydrogen atoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is only half an answer. I'd be thankful if someone could chip in with the rest.

When you want structural information about proteins, the first place to look is the [Protein Data Bank](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do), a freely accessible repository of protein structures determined by techniques such as X-ray crystallography, protein NMR and neutron diffraction, among others.

The problem now is being sure about what you want to find. A basic search for human hemoglobin currently provides [190 hits](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/results/results.do?qrid=9E09BD9C&tabtoshow=Current), so you need to browse a bit to find the most adequate entry. To keep things simple, I looked for a structure for adult hemoglobin, with no mutations, ligands or associations with other proteins. There are some database entries which seem to be right on target, namely [2DN2](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=2DN2) for deoxyhemoglobin and [2DN1](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=2DN1) for oxyhemoglobin.

There is a lot of information in each entry page. The whole structure can be downloaded as a .pdb and opened in appropriate structure visualization programs, of which there are probably several free options. Depending on the program used, retrieving the empirical formula can be trivial.

Forgoing the use of molecular visualization software, there is an "Experimental Data & Validation" section in the protein page, containing a "Full Validation Report" link to a PDF file. There, you can find a section called "Entry Composition" with useful information. For example, in the deoxyhemoglobin structure there are 4777 non-hydrogen atoms. The protein is composed of two copies each of two unique subunits (the alpha and beta subunits), totalling four subunits. The alpha subunit contains 1069 non-hydrogen atoms (685 $\ce{C}$, 187 $\ce{N}$, 194 $\ce{O}$ and 3 $\ce{S}$), while the beta subunit contains 1123 non-hydrogen atoms (724 $\ce{C}$, 195 $\ce{N}$, 201 $\ce{O}$ and 3 $\ce{S}$). Additionally, each subunit also contains one molecule of protoporphyrin IX coordinated to an iron atom. One important thing to note is that the structure also contains solvent molecules, in this case a total of 221 molecules of water, which must be removed from the atom count.

The only flaw is that hydrogen atoms are not shown. This is because X-ray crystallography measurements generally cannot detect hydrogen atoms, and so they are usually added separately to the backbone of the protein, in such a way to complete all atom valencies. I don't know how this can be done other than using a program.

A last thing to keep in mind is that no matter how good the measurement or the data processing, you can very well end up a few atoms off, especially regarding hydrogen atoms. Hopefully perfect precision is not required.